# paintcode and "use of string literal for Objective-C selectors is deprecated; use '#selector' instead"

Tags: paintcode

Since the update to xCode 7.3 and swift 2.2 code generated by PaintCode now produces the following warnings:

Use of string literal for Objective-C selectors is deprecated; use '#selector' instead

Can this be resolved via PaintCode configuration or do we have to wait on a update of PaintCode app itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you purchased from the online store, the update is already available. In case you purchased from the Mac App Store, it will be available in the next few days.

Comment: Got it from the appstore, will have some patient then :-)

Answer (score 0):

It would help to see the code you got from PaintCode, but you should be able to fix it by replacing any occurrences of `selector: Selector("methodName")` or `selector: "methodName"` with `selector: #selector(methodName)`

[Here is an explanation](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0022-objc-selectors.md) of how the new selector syntax works. Also, clicking on the warning in Xcode should show you what to replace it with.

Comment: The thing is, I dont want to be changing the code manually, as I regenerate it often when new design elements are added in PaintCode. So I guess I will just have to wait on the update.